# TypeError: Object of type 'mappingproxy' is not JSON serializable

Tags: python, apache-kafka, avro, confluent-schema-registry, confluent-platform

I am try to publish an avro message using AvroProducer of confluent-kafka-python  using schema-registry. But the code fails to serialize enum types. Below is the code and error trace. Any help is much appreciated.

```
from confluent_kafka import avro
from confluent_kafka.avro import AvroProducer
from example_schema.schema_classes import SCHEMA as value_schema
from example_schema.com.acme import *
import json

def function():
    avroProducer = AvroProducer({ 'bootstrap.servers': 'localhost:9092', 'schema.registry.url': 'http://localhost:8081' },  default_value_schema=value_schema)
    print(avroProducer)
    obj = Test()
    obj.name = 'vinay'
    obj.age = 11
    obj.sex = 'm'
    obj.myenum = Suit.CLUBS
    print(str(obj))
    avroProducer.produce(topic='test_topic',value=obj)
    avroProducer.flush()

function()

  File "main.py", line 16, in function
    avroProducer.produce(topic='test_topic',value=json.dumps(obj))
  File "/home/priv/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/confluent_kafka/avro/__init__.py", line 80, in produce
    value = self._serializer.encode_record_with_schema(topic, value_schema, value)
  File "/home/priv/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/confluent_kafka/avro/serializer/message_serializer.py", line 105, in encode_record_with_schema
    schema_id = self.registry_client.register(subject, schema)
  File "/home/priv/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/confluent_kafka/avro/cached_schema_registry_client.py", line 216, in register
    body = {'schema': json.dumps(avro_schema.to_json())}
  File "/home/priv/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/json/__init__.py", line 231, in dumps
    return _default_encoder.encode(obj)
  File "/home/priv/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/json/encoder.py", line 199, in encode
    chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
  File "/home/priv/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/json/encoder.py", line 257, in iterencode
    return _iterencode(o, 0)
  File "/home/priv/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/json/encoder.py", line 180, in default
    o.__class__.__name__)
TypeError: Object of type 'mappingproxy' is not JSON serializable
```

**Avro Schema -**

```
{
    "type": "record",
    "name": "Test",
    "namespace": "com.acme",
    "fields": [{
            "name": "name",
            "type": "string"
        }, {
            "name": "age",
            "type": "int"
        }, {
            "name": "sex",
            "type": "string"
        }, {
            "name": "myenum",
            "type": ["null", {
                    "type": "enum",
                    "name": "Suit",
                    "symbols": ["SPADES", "HEARTS", "DIAMONDS", "CLUBS"]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Confluent-Kafka python API has compatibility issue with avro-python3  1.9.0 as per this [link](https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-python/issues/610). The solution which worked for me was to Downgrade the avro-python3 API from 1.9.0 to 1.8.2.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using the AvroProducer, don't `json.dumps` anything.

If you look at the examples of the producer, the object being sent is a dictionary, not a JSON string

https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-python/blob/master/examples/avro-cli.py

Answer (score -1):

If you have no option to downgrade the avro-python3 API from 1.9.0 to 1.8.2, you might have to give up the `enum` type and replace it with `string` instead.

```
"type": ["null", {
                "type": "enum",
                "name": "Suit",
                "symbols": ["SPADES", "HEARTS", "DIAMONDS", "CLUBS"]
            }
        ]
```

change into

```
"type": ["null", "string"]
```

Comment: Hi Jadug, please familiarise yourself with [answering questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) before you write your next one! Enjoy your stay at SO :)